# Adding camera resource in IoTivity

Tags: iotivity

How to modify the existing simple server and simple server program in the IoTivity build to add camera resource ?

How stream the video in the client via IoTivity framework ?

Answer (score 1):

List down the attributes, properties, data types needed.
You might find resource types from oneiota.org that you can reuse.
Prepare the representation of the resource and change the code in simpleserver to add all the properties you need. You might also need collections or other slightly non-trivial features as part of your server.

Change the class to match your data model.

Hope this helps.